# Не грузит background-color на сайт

Tags: css

```css
body {
    min-width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Book Antiqua, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    }
    
    .panel{
    background: lightgreen; 
    }
    
    .main-menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    }
    
    .main-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
    }
    
    .main-menu a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    color: rgb(42, 52, 56);
    border-left: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    border-right: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    }
    
    .main-menu a:hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
    }
    
    .main-menu .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #FCF8E3;
    display:none;
    }
    
    .main-menu .sub-menu a {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    
    }
    
    .main-menu > li:hover .sub-menu {
    display:block;
    }
```

Через css задал для класса div background-color. Он отображается на странице только локально, а когда загружаю на хостинг, то уже нет. Проверял через источник страницы и на онлайн-сайте почему-то удаляется этот стиль в css. 
При загрузке на сайт пропадает panel и main-menu a:hover изменяется цвет. Прошу помощи.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Что значит "удаляется"? У вас этот код системой деплоя удаляется из итогового css? Или в инспекторе браузера перечёркивается? Грузятся ли хостером дополнительные скрипты? Вообще, набор скриптов тот же?

Comment: Напишите свой код. Могу предложить - или кеш или не правельно написаный путь

Comment: Как вы задаете стиль: в отдельном файле или на самой странице? Если в отдельном файле загружаете ли вы его на хостинг? А если загружаете, с путями проблем не возникает?

Comment: Его нет на сайте. Хостинг поддерживает другие скрипты.

Comment: Css в отдельном файле, там много стилей, но удаляется именно background-color.